# How can I repeat last Ex-mode command in normal mode?

Tags: search, normal-mode, ex-mode, repeated-commands

I'm looking for something like `.` or `@@` that will work in normal mode for repeating the last Ex-mode command.

As per the rule of the XY problem, I'll also state the broader goal:

I have a fancy regex search and replace command in Ex-mode that I want to apply to *almost* all matches in the file.  But I need to review each one before I change it.  If I could use `.` to repeat an Ex-mode command, I could just use `n` and `.` to do what I need.

So any way to apply my search and replace to all lines **interactively** would help me—but I'd still be interested in an answer to the title question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `/c` flag at the end of your substitution in order to confirm each substitution:

```
:%s/foo/bar/gc
```

See `:help s_flags`.

Use `&` to repeat the last substitution *without the flags*. See `:help &`.

Use `@:` to repeat the last ex command.

Comment: Perfect.  Everything I asked for.  :)