# How to repeat the last command in Ex?

Tags: repeated-commands, ex-command

I've the file, like:

```
name = foo
# unknown number of lines ...
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule1 
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule2 
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule3 
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule4
```

and I'd like to run [`:/_exclude/s///`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7195/467) command on it and repeat it one more time (`@:`).

I've tried things suggested in [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5165/467), however it doesn't work.

So when using `@:` to repeat the last command-line change, it gives me the error:

> E30: No previous command line

So it seems it doesn't recognise what was the previous command line.

Here is example:

```
$ ex '+:/_exclude/s///p' '+@:' -scwq -V1 foo.txt 
"foo.txt" 
"foo.txt" 10 lines, 375 characters
search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP
features[rules_config][] = rule1 

Error detected while processing command line:
E30: No previous command line
"foo.txt" 
"foo.txt" 10 lines, 367 characters written
```

Why is that?
Are there any other reliable ways of repeating the last Ex command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[:help E30](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#E30) states

> The command-line is only stored in this register when at least one character of it was typed.  Thus it remains unchanged if the command was completed from a mapping.

It seems like Vim is not considering commands specified via `+` (or `-c`) to be typed, so `":` isn't updated.

I'm not sure if that's expected behavior or just an oversight.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine there must be an easier way. Since `@:` is accessing a special register, you can use registers yourself:

```
$ vim -Nesc ":let @a = '/_exclude/s///p'" +@a +@a +wq foo    
features[rules_config][] = rule1 
features[rules_config][] = rule2
```