# Is it possible to copy block (given by range) multiple times in a single command?

Tags: command-line, ex-command, range

Is there a way to copy a few times a given block from command-line mode, e.g. with the `:t` command?

For example, how to copy the two lines (block) above the cursor `-2,-1` to the current position `.`, 3 times with one command instead of three:

```
: -2,-1t.
: -2,-1t.
: -2,-1t.
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you mean. Could you provide some examples to make it more clear?

Comment: You can repeat the last Ex command with `@:` and further repeats can be done with `@@`

Comment: Related to [How to repeat the last command in Ex?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7201/12003) — Perhaps you can try operating on a special register as muru's answer suggested: `let @a = '-2,-1t.' | exe @a @a @a`